# How can I construct an SVG scene with user coordinates to fill the screen

Tags: svg, image-scaling

I am displaying a diagrammatic map using SVG and it must be proportional (i.e., not skewed x/y).

The image fills the whole screen so the outer  item is always 100%/100%. In other words I want the viewport to always fill the browser windows (within the constraints of aspect ratio), for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" >
    <defs>
        <solidColor xml:id="solidBlack" solid-color="black" />
        <solidColor xml:id="solidLightGray" solid-color="lightgrey" />
    </defs>
    <style>
        .Border { fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width="2px" }
        .TitleBlock { fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width="1px" }
    </style>
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1000 1000" >
        <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" class="Border" />
        <svg viewbox="500 500 500 500">
            <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
            <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
            <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
        </svg>  
    </svg>
</svg>
```

When this renders, the values are being interpreted as pixels, not user coordinates. So, for example, the green dot should be near the bottom of the screen (since it is at the bottom of the viewbox) but in actuality it is in the middle of the screen because it is interpreting 490 as 490 pixels.

To further clarify, the 1000 x 1000 dimensions of the total map area are user coordinates. For example, suppose I am making a space game and the game area is 1000 parsecs x 1000 parsecs. Any particular view of this map area should fill the screen.

**Update**

Based on the answer one fundamental problem is that to fill the screen I need to use 100% in the outer svg element. However, even after doing this, the image is not zooming in and using user coordinates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" 
    width="100%" height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 100000 100000" >
    <defs>
        <solidColor xml:id="solidBlack" solid-color="black" />
        <solidColor xml:id="solidLightGray" solid-color="lightgrey" />
    </defs>
    <style>
        .Border { fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width="2px"; }
        .TitleBlock { fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width="1px"; }
    }
    </style>
    <rect y="2" width="100%" height="100%" class="Border" />
    <svg viewBox="50000 50000 100000 100000" >
        <circle  cx="52000"  cy="52000" r="10px" fill="red" />
        <circle cx="95000"  cy="53000" r="10px" fill="blue" />
        <circle  cx="54000" cy="99000" r="10px" fill="green" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

This does not even appear at all, indicating it is using PIXELS not user coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused about how viewBox works.  It describes the bounds of the document that should be scaled to fit the viewport (width & height). It doesn't perform a transform.

Your viewBox of "500 500 500 500" describes the area (500,500) -> (1000,1000).  So your coordinate of (10,490) will normally end up way outside the viewport.

Having said that, it is not at all clear what you are actually trying to achieve with your nested set of `<svg>` elements.

I'm going to assume you are wanting to display a portion of your 1000x1000 world map so it fills the screen?  Lets' start by simplifying your original SVG.

```css
.Border { fill:none; stroke:red; stroke-width="2px" }
.TitleBlock { fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width="1px" }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="100%" height="100%"
    viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <defs>
        <solidColor xml:id="solidBlack" solid-color="black" />
        <solidColor xml:id="solidLightGray" solid-color="lightgrey" />
    </defs>
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" class="Border" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Here we are displaying the whole world map in an SVG that is 100%x100%.  Due to the way percentage width/height values are processed for SVGs and because the viewBox is square.  This normally results in an SVG that is 100% width and whose height is equivalent to the width, resulting in an SVG that may end up off the bottom of the page.

If you want the SVG viewport to match the screen exactly you should use a width/height in pixels, not percents.  For the sake of fitting in the snippet window, let's choose a tiny screen of 512x384 (1/2 of a 1024x768 screen).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="512" height="384"
    viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

    <rect x="-50%" y="-50" width="200%" height="200%" fill="#ffc"/>
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Here I've also added a light yellow rectangle to show the dimensions of the viewport (screen) and how the viewBox has resulted in the "world" being scaled to fit the screen.

If you want the world to fill the screen and not have the blank areas to the left and right you need to change the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.  By default it is set to `xMidYMid meet` which means scale the viewBox area up to neatly fit the viewport and centre it.  If we change it to `xMidYMid slice`, it will scale it up to fill the widest part of the viewport.  That results in the top and bottom of your "world" going off screen.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="512" height="384"
    viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">

    <rect x="-50%" y="-50" width="200%" height="200%" fill="#ffc"/>
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Now, if you want to view a portion of your "world", for example the top left, you would set the viewBox to "0 0 500 500".  If you want to see the whole of that area, use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet":

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="512" height="384"
    viewBox="0 0 500 500"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">

    <rect x="-50%" y="-50" width="200%" height="200%" fill="#ffc"/>
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

If you don't want to see parts of the world outside of that 500x500 area, and can live with part of it being offscreen, use `xMidYMid slice`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="512" height="384"
    viewBox="0 0 500 500"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">

    <rect x="-50%" y="-50" width="200%" height="200%" fill="#ffc"/>
    <rect x="2" y="2" width="99%" height="99%" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" />
    <circle cx="30" cy="20" r="10px" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="450" cy="30" r="10px" fill="blue" />
    <circle cx="40" cy="490" r="10px" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Here, your three circles end up just off screen.

Does this help?

Comment: #3 Is what I am after, but the problem here is that you are using PIXELS, not full screen. The values are user coordinates. For example, if green was at (500000, 990000) and the viewbox was "500000 500000 1000000 1000000" then green should appear at the bottom left of the viewport (browser window), which it is not (see my new example above).

Comment: The last two values of the viewBox are width and height, not maxX,maxY.  So for the example in your comment, the green circle would not be at bottom left.It would be halfway down the left side.  http://jsfiddle.net/ab8etatv/

Comment: If the height of the box is 1000000 and the green y-coordinate is at 990000, then it is at the bottom.

Comment: No. You are specifying a minY of 500000, so the bottom of the viewBox is at (500000+1000000) = 1500000.  So 990000 is about half way.